# attachment.add is using defaut location instead of set location

Tags: powershell

I am very new to scripting and PowerShell. have been working on a script that, in part, will email out log files it has generated.  Suddenly my attachment add is no longer working, instead giving me the error

```
Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "test_2015-12-16.log", for "Add" to type "System.Net.Mail.Attachment": "Cannot convert value "test_2015-12-16.log" to type "System.Net.Mail.Attachment". Error: "Could not find file 'C:\
Windows\system32\test_2015-12-16.log'.""
At line:8 char:23
+ $email.attachments.add <<<< ($realFiles[$i])
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

In the script I have earlier `set-location $emailLogTarget`, and the code where I'm having trouble is:

```
$AttachmentList = get-childitem -path $EmailLogTarget -include "*.log" -name
$AttachmentList
$realFiles = $AttachmentList | ? {Test-Path -Path $_}
for ($i=0; $i -lt $realFiles.length; $i++)
{
    new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($realFiles[$i])
    $email.attachments.add($realFiles[$i])
}
```

Why is this code using the default path instead of the currently set location?

I am using Powershell version 2.0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have identified the issue.  Using `Set-Location` will change the working location, but the working directory remained the same.  I needed to change `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory` to the directory that I was pulling files from.

Answer (score 1):

Because you added `-Name` to your `Get-ChildItem` call, and that returned a list of the file names instead of the full paths.

Remove `-Name` and then use my suggestion below.

<s>Because `$attachmentList` is not a list of files as strings, it's a list of `[System.IO.FileInfo]` objects, and when embedded into a string, or casted to a string in this case, as each one is passed into the constructor for the attachment object, they are displayed as the file name only, not the full path.</s>

Instead, you can just use the `.FullName` property:

```
$AttachmentList = get-childitem -path $EmailLogTarget -include "*.log"
for ($i=0; $i -lt $realFiles.length; $i++)
{
    new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($realFiles[$i].FullName)
    $email.attachments.add($realFiles[$i]) # I imagine you don't want the full name here
}
```

Comment: Unless I am interpreting this wrong, $AttachmentList is stored as strings. running $realfiles.fullname gives me no data.  That is the right syntax to check the value, right?

Comment: @rStyskel what version of powershell? `$realFiles.FullName` will only work on PowerShell 3+. `$realFiles[0].FullName` should show you the first one on any version of PowerShell. `$AttachmentList` is not a list of strings. You can check `$AttachmentList | Get-Member` to see what each member's type is.

Comment: TypeName: System.String.  I'm using version 2.0

Comment: @rStyskel my mistake, I didn't see that you added `-Name` to `Get-ChildItem`. See my edit.

Comment: Using the code in the edit, $AttachmentList is empty.  I feel doubly confused as the original code was working yesterday before I left for the night.

Comment: @rStyskel are you still doing `Set-Location` with the new code?

Comment: Yes.  i'm working in ISE right now as well, so they should still be set anyway I believe.